# Can not upload with some different files on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I try to upload data with different type of extension with codeigniter but I have constraints file it does not go into the folder that I go. i try to make some config according to what i need, please help ..

```
function add_module_external(){
    $id_module = '9090909';
    $file_data = array();
    $file_data2 = array();
    $image_data = array();
    $config_video = array();


    $config_image["file_name"] = $id_module;
    $config_image["upload_path"] = "./assets/file/image-module/";
    $config_image["overwrite"] = TRUE;
    $config_image["allowed_types"] = "gif|jpg|png|";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config_image); 
    $this->upload->initialize($config_image);
    $upload_background = $this->upload->do_upload('other_image');
    if($upload_background){
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $image = $image_data['file_name'];
    }else{
        $image = $this->input->post('background');
    }


    // pdf and ppt upload       
    $config_file['file_name'] = $id_module;
    $config_file['upload_path'] = '/assets/file/materi-module/';
    $config_file['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config_file); 
    $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
    $upload_pdf = $this->upload->do_upload('pdf_data'); 

    if($upload_pdf){
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $content = $file_data["file_name"];         
        }else if($upload_ppt){
            $file_data2 = $this->upload->data();
            $content = $file_data2["file_name"]; 
        }else if($upload_video){
            $config_video = $this->upload->data();
            $content = $config_video["file_name"]; 
        }else{
            $content = $this->input->post("text_data");
        }   


    $query = $this->my_module->new_module($image, $id_module, $content);
            redirect($this->agent->referrer());     

}
```

Comment: what you mean by `different type of extension`

Comment: i have 2 data that is pdf and image